# Should I avoid JS when possible and use CSS instead?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm looking for best practice answer. Currently I'm trying to add a dropdown menu to the navigation bar of my website. I've found that I could do it using CSS and that I could also do it using JS - Angular. I've read that because with JS malicious things can be programmed some people disable JS. Therefore to keep your websites functionality on more computers it should be programmed in CSS. Is there any merit to this? Should I avoid coding in JS when possible?

Comment: Depends on what you're doing, every developer's opinions will differ and CSS does have its limitations in terms of creating an interactive web experience. Something else to consider is that if you use certain newer/experimental CSS features, you could similarly be cutting out a significant population from properly using your site due to spotty browser support. There's no clear-cut answer to this question. (Unless you want to build a pretty non-interactive site consisting of just static links and...uh, animated GIFs, well, someone is going to get an inferior UX.)

Comment: I object to the question being put on hold, as the answers so far have shown to agree with each other and that CSS is a best practice for the reasons provided in the answers below. Of course there are exceptions and there always will be but in general the answer to my question is to use CSS whenever possible.

Comment: You can make a full CSS dropdown menu since IE6, but there are many many cases where you can't avoid js (Ajax for example). Btw I don't agree with the answers. I can't choose between "primarily opinion based" and "too broad" then :-/

Comment: If you are looking to solve just for the dropdown, CSS or JS shouldn't matter much, provided, you are doing it the right way. Else, my answer should give you enough information about the comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are few important reasons why you should prefer using CSS over JS.

- CSS animations are much better in performance compared to JS
  animations. CSS doesn't take as much memory as JS for rendering animations.
- If your animation depends on the screen width, CSS media queries work like a charm without any lag. But if you have to achieve this using JS, you will have to bind an event to the window size and perform an action on every resize.
- Javascript animations always have slightly higher overhead than CSS animations because in the end JS animations would be manipulating the CSS styles for animations.

However, like how they say, every advantage has its disadvantage. CSS animations don't give the freedom to perform any animation.

> Animating the scale, rotation, and position of an element is incredibly common. In CSS, they're all crammed into one "transform" property, making them impossible to animate in a truly distinct way on a single element. For example, what if you want to animate "rotation" and "scale" independently, with different timings and eases? Maybe an element is continuously pulsing (oscillating scale) and you'd like to rotate it on rollover. That's only possible with JavaScript.

**Reference:** [Myth Busting: CSS Animations vs. JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/#article-header-id-0)

If you want the flexibility of JS animations and the speed of CSS animations, you should try [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap), which is built on JavaScript and is much faster than CSS animations. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/#article-header-id-4) is the performance test comparing CSS animations (using [Zepto](http://www.zeptojs.com/)), [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) animations and [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) animations. Not to forget, the results may vary as per the rendering engine.

**Conclusion:**
This is how you can go about it.

Simple animations, CSS achievable: Use CSS

Simple animations, can't achieve with CSS: Use JS

Heavy animations: Use [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) or craft your animations with [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame).

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Performance/CSS_JavaScript_animation_performance) is an amazing performance comparison between CSS animation and JS `requestAnimationFrame` implementations.