# Display child-element with hover, hide it when focus is lost

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, focus

I have an element `(dropdown-content)` that is displayed when its parent (Element2) is hovered. When no interaction with the element `(dropdown-content)` occurs I want it to act as it does now and disappear when the hover is over. But when the element gets focus (the select or input or somewhere else in the dropdown-content are clicked) I want it to stay displayed until it loses focus (clicked somewhere outside the `dropdown-content`), even when the coursor leaves the `dropdown-content`.
I have already tried to find a solution with the search and several things using CSS `and/or` javascript but was not able to archive what I want. Here is an example code to illustrate my problem:

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content,
.dropdown-content:focus {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Element1</li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <span>Element2</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <select>
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>Element3</li>
</ul>
```

I would prefer a CSS solution if there is a clean one but I am also fine with javascript, but I don't want a JQuery solution if this is possible. If this makes the solution way easier it would be also fine if the `dropdown-contet` just stays displayed when there is focus on the select and input only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need Javascript let alone jQuery for that. It can and [should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466129/should-i-avoid-js-when-possible-and-use-css-instead) be done with pure CSS with the pseudo-class [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within).

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: -3px 0 0 3px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content, .dropdown-content:focus-within {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Element1</li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <span>Element2</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <select>
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>Element3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted and solved my problem! I was already assuming that there is such a simple solution, but I was missing :focus-within, thank you very much!

Comment: @Phaneroptera You're welcome. I changed `block` to `inline-block` and added some margins so it get's displayed next to Element2.

Comment: This is nice. i didn't aware of this `:focus-within`. Thanks for sharing.