# There are different ways to handle resize events for your html document, is there a difference?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw that you can change styles with the CSS @media Rule, and you can also add     `window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);` in your javascript to change your document depending one its size.

Is there any difference and should you use one over the other? Or are they interchangeable?

Comment: One is CSS and the other is JavaScript! Given CSS @media is built in to the browser it is _likely_ more efficient than any piece of JavaScript you write.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do something in pure CSS, avoid using JavaScript.

I thought this was always true, but surprisingly from what I read, it is not always true especially when we speak about animations :

> In most cases, the performance of CSS-based animations is almost the same as JavaScripted animations — in Firefox at least. Some JavaScript-based animation libraries, like GSAP and Velocity.JS, even claim that they are able to achieve better performance than native CSS transitions/animations

-- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/CSS_JavaScript_animation_performance#performance_comparisontransitions_vs._requestanimationframe)

An other interesting link about CSS vs JS : [SO : Should I avoid JS when possible and use CSS instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466129/should-i-avoid-js-when-possible-and-use-css-instead)

**For classic uses** (change mobile, tablet and desktop view), **pure css is more efficient** with `media queries`.

I'm hoping for new answers and get more informations about when prioritize JS than CSS.